# Ext Js + Sencha-touch

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch

Is possible to integrate `sencha touch` with a `ExtJS` project?

I am using ExtJS 3.2.1.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: **Yes**

Long answer: ExtJS is a javascript framework, which provides GUI elements, along with tools for manipulating the DOM and such, and is designed for writing webapps. Sencha-touch is specifically designed for mobile webapps. So, while it may be possible to integrate the two, I am not sure why you would want to. Taking a quick look at the [Sencha Touch documentation](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/touch/docs/), it should provide all the tools you need.

So yes, you can integrate the two, but I don't know why you would want to.

Comment: I have a project I am working on where both libraries are used; however, not at the same time... we use Touch for mobile UI and standard for non-mobile. I am sure there are reasons why they created a separate project rather than just making ExtJS mobile-ready.

Comment: Mobile, especially touch, is handled a bit differently. As a toy example, a 'click' event is not handled the same way as a 'touch' event. As well, in terms of design, there are different constraints on mobile vs web, so an optimized version makes sense for one experience or another.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can very easily. However - what you will end up with is a desktop app which looks like it should be running on a mobile device. You also have to trade off specific features which are best suited for desktop (like grids and paging).

Plus - if you develop a desktop app using Sencha Touch - it won't for for all browsers. Specifically it will run best only in Chrome, Firefox and Safari.

Answer (score 1):

Sencha Ext JS 5.0 and Sencha Touch use much of the same code. If you are able to upgrade to 5.0 it will make your job much easier. This is one of the goals of sencha with each new version it releases, to write code once (in Ext JS) and have it run on both desktop and mobile devices with minimal code changes. There is an example on the Sencha blog at: http://www.sencha.com/blog/reusing-code-in-ext-js-5-and-sencha-touch-apps-to-build-a-sencha-space-app/